# The Access Token is Valid but We get OAuthException: An active access token error

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token, uncaught-exception

We've been working on an application for about 2 months, and everything was going perfectly. 
we were using PHP SDK and offline mode in permissions for login 
But since some days ago after recent changes in Facebook api and removing offline mode we started facing the problem of "Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

The main problem is that it does happen after a while working in our app (about 10 mins) but at the same time when we check the validity of the token via [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token)
we see that the token is still valid on the other hand the cookie does still exist and it doesn't expire but we get this error : 
"Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

[I've already visited this link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148) 
and I downloaded the latest version but it didn't help could anyone help us please where might be making mistake?

---

Thanks for responses, I think same as yacon 
it seems there's a bug when accessing facebook->api(/me) at the moment we are handling 
some parts of the app with javascript which is a real headache to use javascript sdk 
and PhP sdk alongside with each other

Comment: by the way I think I should mention that when we delete the cookies from our websites in the browser we could successfully login again but after a while the same things happen

Comment: If you use the PHP sdk then this uses the session to store the token - what is your session expiration?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. So, following this thread and very interested about proposed solutions

Comment: Also having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this simply store accesstoken to session variable after getLoginUrl

> $facebook->getLoginUrl(...)

then whenever you initialize facebook

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => Yii::app()->params['facebook_appId'],
  'secret' => Yii::app()->params['facebook_appSecret'],
));
```

get the accesstoken from session and set it using setAccessToken

> $facebook->setAccessToken(Yii::app()->session['access_token']);

Answer (score 1):

I handle this situation in this way
1.i get the access token for 1 hour validity
2.extend the token to 60 days validity
3.save that token to session and use it for all project queries.

```
         try{
               $facebook_uid = $facebook->getUser();
                $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
                $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');
                $session['api_me'] = $fbuser;
                $session['tokenValue'] = $accessToken;
        }catch (Exception $e) {
                facebook_uid =null;
        }
```

Comment: $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me'); it contains the user info.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm trying your code... i hope that it helps with the new changes into the PHP SDK

Comment: One more thing, $session shouldn't be $_SESSION['api_me'] or $_SESSION['tokenValue'] ?

Comment: Hemc what do you mean by using this accessToken in further queries Let's say I need to access facebook->api(/me) and then at this line
exception happens so how to use accessToken saved in session to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the api. When I use $facebook->api('/'.$facebook_uid) instead of ->api('/me') it works.

Comment: I think same as yacon it seems there's a bug when accessing facebook->api(/me) at the moment we are handling some parts of the app with javascript which is a real headache to use javascript sdk and PhP sdk alongside with each other