# Facebook php sdk api('/me'), doesnt always respond

Tags: facebook, yii, facebook-php-sdk

At the moment i'm trying to get the info of my logged in users. But I got a problem, i build this in an function in Yii, and this does work. But sometimes it doesn't.

When i go to the function it does the following:

```
$accesToken = Yii::app()->facebook->getAccessToken();
$results = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me');
print_r($results);
```

When i launch this i get all the info, but when i refresh the same page it gives the following error:

```
Error 500
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

And the weirdest thing is, when i wait a few seconds and i refresh again it gives me the info of the user like on first load of the function.

So i am really stuck on how i can solve this problem, cause i really don't have any clue why it works one time, and not the second time.

The whole function is:

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $facebookID = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();

    if($facebookID == 0) {

            echo 'No Facebook id.';

    } else {
        $record = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('FB_id'=>$facebookID));
        if($record===null) {

            echo 'Got facebookID but not in database!';
            echo $facebookID;
        } else {

            $accesToken = Yii::app()->facebook->getAccessToken();
            $results = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me');
            print_r($results);
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo $accesToken;
            //echo 'Got facebookID and is in database!';
        }
    }
    /*
    echo $facebookID;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $accesToken;
    */
}
```

Comment: which sdk version you are using? latest is php sdk 3.2.2

Comment: The real issue here is, are you inspecting what data that access token gives? Or is it even a valid access token?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$results = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me?access_token=' . $accesToken);`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me: [The Access Token is Valid but We get OAuthException: An active access token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777181/the-access-token-is-valid-but-we-get-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-erro)

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $this->appId,
        'secret' => $this->appSecret,
    ));
    $this->facebook->setAccessToken(Yii::app()->session['access_token']);
}
```